# Sharing a value within report by a Gvlobal Variable

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a group(Group 2) for Pay types where there is two types.
Pay Types
 1) Earnings 
 2) Deductions

The details are grouped by these two pay types.

In Earnings I have the record NetSalary.I need to take the NetSalary later to another group called Employe (Group 1 in my case) to set the net salary.

//@NetSalary=BasicSalary+SUM(Earnings)

```
//Formula NSal
WhilePRINTINGRecords;
Global NumberVar x;
IF({PAY_TYPE}="EARNINGS") then
x := {@NetSalary}
```

The net salary always shows in the earning type in group but when I try to keep the global variable X in Group 1 it always shows null/zero.

Can I do it as above by a global variable?

Comment: Instead this way you can try using arrays

Comment: Please detail will you

Answer (score 0):

Follow below method:

Create a formula `@Store` and write below code and place in group footer 2 and supress it;

```
Shared Stringvar array store;

store:=store+Totext(Sum ({netsalary},{Group2})

store[1]
```

Now create one more formula `@Display` and write below code and place in group footer 1:

```
Shared Stringvar array store;

store[1]
```

Display this.. here `[1]` is first value in array and `[2]` is second value and so on.. depends on number of values you store